# How to display top 3 items in WPF bound collection?

Tags: wpf

I am creating a control that displays a summary of data. On this page I am binding a control to an ObservableColection that contains many items. I created a CollectionView that sorts the items by time but in this control I only want to show the top 3 items. I tried creating a converter to accomplish this but all ways I try to filter the list return a "new" list and the control is no longer updated when a new item is added to the master ObservableCollection.

Is there a clean way to accomplish this? I will have to do something similar for several of my collections so I would like to make something generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the ViewModel pattern, the ***clean way*** is to have another ObservableCollection with the top N items. That way the binding is direct and you can change 3 to whatever N you want only by changing your model.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> myList;

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList 
    { 
        get { return myList; }
        set { return myList; }
    }

    public Collection<string> MyListTop3 
    {
        get { return new Collection<string>(MyList.Take(3).ToList()); }
    }

    public MyViewModel() 
    {
        myList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        myList.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
        { 
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyListTop3");
        }; 
    } 
}
```

If you want to that care of it only through XAML (**no the *cleaneast way***):

```
<ListBox>

    <ListBox.Resources>
        <ContentPresenter x:Key="value0" Content="{Binding MyList[0]}"/>
        <ContentPresenter x:Key="value1" Content="{Binding MyList[1]}"/>
        <ContentPresenter x:Key="value2" Content="{Binding MyList[2]}"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>

    <ListBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource value0}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource value1}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource value2}"/>

</ListBox>
```

This example shows a *ListBox* but you can use it on any other control.

Comment: Using your first method, if some UI control was bound to `MyListTop3`, would it automatically update its contents whenever `MyList` updates? Or would you have to raise property change notification for `MyListTop3` explicitly whenever `MyList` updates? Just curious.

Comment: Sure, you've to notify changes some way. To be correct MyListTop3 isn't a truly ObservableCollection because you aren't adding items to it but building it through another collection (that being the observable one). Updated my answer for completeness.

Comment: That way it will be updated whenever you make a change to main list *MyList*.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but I wasn't sure. Good solution, and thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially what I ended up doing. I just updated the filtered list, that my control is bound to, in the master list's CollectionChanged event directly.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the built in filtering of the CollectionView to do this. In the Filter predicate you can use the original collection and sort it the same way as your view sort and check the index.

```
FilteredList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };

_defaultView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(FilteredList);
_defaultView.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription(".", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
_defaultView.Filter = o =>
{
    int index = FilteredList.OrderBy(s => s).ToList().IndexOf(o as string);
    return index >= 0 && index < 3;
};
```

You will also need to make sure the view gets refreshed any time an item gets added - either by including it with the code that does the adding or in a handler on the CollectionChanged event.

```
FilteredList.Add(newItem);
_defaultView.Refresh();
```

Comment: Much cleaner solution than accepted answer, you do not need to hold addition collection, just filtered view and you can simply change the view on demand at runtime between filtered/full view.